# setFill() & setStroke() not importing correctly

Tags: java, javafx

I am starting JavaFx, and I would like to assign a fill and an outline to my circle, I quickly find the functions setFill () and setStroke () but my Eclipse does not understand them and I cannot find out why!

My code :

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Circle cercle = new Circle(100,100,75);
    cercle.setFill(Color.YELLOW); 
    cercle.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600, Color.YELLOW);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please include the *exact* error, and when it occurs.

Comment: (You seem to be trying to run arbitrary code outside of a method or initializer, though; a Java tutorial might be in order.)

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to call the `setFill()` and `setStroke()` methods in your start (or another) method.
2. You need to add the circle to the `BorderPane`:

```
public class App extends Application
{
```

`static Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 75);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    try
    {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.YELLOW);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`

Comment: OW Thanks ! It's good now ! I did not know that it was necessary to put them in a method, We can put the question in solved: D

Comment: @MaxenceQuinet Please don't edit the question title or body to mark the question as solved. Instead, accept the answer which best solved the problem—see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).